# Android Jetpack Compose: How to show styled Text from string resources

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have a string in my `strings.xml` which is localized for different languages.
The strings are styled with Html tags for each localization.

Using Android `TextView`, I was able to show the styled text just fine by reading the string resources.

Considering that Jetpack Compose currently `(1.0.0-rc02)` does not support Html tags, I tried using `TextView` inside an `AndroidView` composable following Official Docs: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose

Example of what I tried:

```
@Composable
fun StyledText(text: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    AndroidView(
            modifier = modifier,
            factory = { context -> TextView(context) },
            update = {
                it.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
            }
    )
}
```

The text in `strings.xml` file:

```
<string name="styled_text">Sample text with <b>bold styling</b> to test</string>
```

However, using `stringResource(id = R.string.styled_text)` provides the text **without** the Html tags.

Is there a way to show text **from string resources** with Html styles in Jetpack Compose?

---

The following two questions are similar, but they **do not** read the string from resources:

[Jetpack compose display html in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68085926/jetpack-compose-display-html-in-text)

[Android Compose: How to use HTML tags in a Text view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66494838/android-compose-how-to-use-html-tags-in-a-text-view)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`stringResource` under the hood uses `resources.getString`, which discards any styled information. You need to create something like `textResource` to get the raw value:

```
@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun textResource(@StringRes id: Int): CharSequence =
    LocalContext.current.resources.getText(id)
```

And use it like this:

```
StyledText(textResource(id = R.string.foo))

@Composable
fun StyledText(text: CharSequence, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context -> TextView(context) },
        update = {
            it.text = text
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works for old android TextView just fine! `stringResource` seems to skip the Html tags completely.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked! Wrapping up what I understood from your answer: using `resources.getText()` returns a char sequence if the resource is styled. Also, we still have to use the View-based `TextView`. Well done!

For everyone else, more info about `resources.getText()` in official docs: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getText(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Just be aware that this does not use the theme's typography.

Comment: For anyone needing the same for array string resources, use:

`@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun textArrayResource(@ArrayRes id: Int): Array<CharSequence> {
    val resources = LocalContext.current.resources
    return resources.getTextArray(id)
}`

Comment: nice solution. I extended textResource by `.replace("\n +".toRegex(),"\n").trim()`

Answer (score 13):

There is ongoing discussion to implement on Jetpack Compose UI:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139320238

After some research, I came me up with the following solution that I also posted in the same discussion:

```kotlin
@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
private fun resources(): Resources {
    LocalConfiguration.current
    return LocalContext.current.resources
}

fun Spanned.toHtmlWithoutParagraphs(): String {
    return HtmlCompat.toHtml(this, HtmlCompat.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE)
        .substringAfter("<p dir=\"ltr\">").substringBeforeLast("</p>")
}

fun Resources.getText(@StringRes id: Int, vararg args: Any): CharSequence {
    val escapedArgs = args.map {
        if (it is Spanned) it.toHtmlWithoutParagraphs() else it
    }.toTypedArray()
    val resource = SpannedString(getText(id))
    val htmlResource = resource.toHtmlWithoutParagraphs()
    val formattedHtml = String.format(htmlResource, *escapedArgs)
    return HtmlCompat.fromHtml(formattedHtml, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
}

@Composable
fun annotatedStringResource(@StringRes id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): AnnotatedString {
    val resources = resources()
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    return remember(id, formatArgs) {
        val text = resources.getText(id, *formatArgs)
        spannableStringToAnnotatedString(text, density)
    }
}

@Composable
fun annotatedStringResource(@StringRes id: Int): AnnotatedString {
    val resources = resources()
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    return remember(id) {
        val text = resources.getText(id)
        spannableStringToAnnotatedString(text, density)
    }
}

private fun spannableStringToAnnotatedString(
    text: CharSequence,
    density: Density
): AnnotatedString {
    return if (text is Spanned) {
        with(density) {
            buildAnnotatedString {
                append((text.toString()))
                text.getSpans(0, text.length, Any::class.java).forEach {
                    val start = text.getSpanStart(it)
                    val end = text.getSpanEnd(it)
                    when (it) {
                        is StyleSpan -> when (it.style) {
                            Typeface.NORMAL -> addStyle(
                                SpanStyle(
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal
                                ),
                                start,
                                end
                            )
                            Typeface.BOLD -> addStyle(
                                SpanStyle(
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal
                                ),
                                start,
                                end
                            )
                            Typeface.ITALIC -> addStyle(
                                SpanStyle(
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic
                                ),
                                start,
                                end
                            )
                            Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC -> addStyle(
                                SpanStyle(
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic
                                ),
                                start,
                                end
                            )
                        }
                        is TypefaceSpan -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(
                                fontFamily = when (it.family) {
                                    FontFamily.SansSerif.name -> FontFamily.SansSerif
                                    FontFamily.Serif.name -> FontFamily.Serif
                                    FontFamily.Monospace.name -> FontFamily.Monospace
                                    FontFamily.Cursive.name -> FontFamily.Cursive
                                    else -> FontFamily.Default
                                }
                            ),
                            start,
                            end
                        )
                        is BulletSpan -> {
                            Log.d("StringResources", "BulletSpan not supported yet")
                            addStyle(SpanStyle(), start, end)
                        }
                        is AbsoluteSizeSpan -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(fontSize = if (it.dip) it.size.dp.toSp() else it.size.toSp()),
                            start,
                            end
                        )
                        is RelativeSizeSpan -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(fontSize = it.sizeChange.em),
                            start,
                            end
                        )
                        is StrikethroughSpan -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough),
                            start,
                            end
                        )
                        is UnderlineSpan -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline),
                            start,
                            end
                        )
                        is SuperscriptSpan -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(baselineShift = BaselineShift.Superscript),
                            start,
                            end
                        )
                        is SubscriptSpan -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(baselineShift = BaselineShift.Subscript),
                            start,
                            end
                        )
                        is ForegroundColorSpan -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(color = Color(it.foregroundColor)),
                            start,
                            end
                        )
                        else -> addStyle(SpanStyle(), start, end)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        AnnotatedString(text.toString())
    }
}
```

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139320238#comment11

With these helper methods, you can simply call:

```kotlin
Text(annotatedStringResource(R.string.your_string_resource))
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can use it in a `Text` Composable?

Comment: Yes, since `Text` supports `AnnotatedString`, you can call `Text(annotatedStringResource(R.string.your_string_resource))`, which was defined in the answer above.

Comment: @superus8r, could you please reconsider what the correct answer it? I don't think that using `AndroidView` is the best solution. The answer provided here uses only Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 2):

To keep using `stringResources()` you can do as down below.

**1st - Use `<![CDATA[ … ]]>`**

Embrace all your resource HTML strings between `<![CDATA[ … ]]>` then you are not going to lose the HTML definitions when calling `stringResources()`:

```
<string name="styled_text"><![CDATA[Sample text with <b>bold styling</b> to test]]></string>
```

**2nd - Create a *"from `Spanned` to `AnnotatedString` processor"***

First of all thanks to [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68935732/2578331).

Then it is important to know that the `text` param *(from `Text()` composable)* does also accept an `AnnotatedString` object and not only a `String`.

Moving forward… we can create a *"from `Spanned` to `AnnotatedString` processor"* algorithm using the Jetpack [`buildAnnotatedString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString.Builder).

In this case I would pick the *"create the algorithm as an extension `private` function inside of the client composable file"* path:

```
private fun Spanned.toAnnotatedString(): AnnotatedString =
    buildAnnotatedString {
        val spanned = this@toAnnotatedString
        append(spanned.toString())

        getSpans(
            0,
            spanned.length,
            Any::class.java
        ).forEach { span ->
            val start = getSpanStart(span)
            val end = getSpanEnd(span)

            when (span) {
                is StyleSpan ->
                    when (span.style) {
                        Typeface.BOLD -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                            start,
                            end
                        )

                        Typeface.ITALIC -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic),
                            start,
                            end
                        )

                        Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC -> addStyle(
                            SpanStyle(
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic
                            ),
                            start,
                            end
                        )
                    }

                is ForegroundColorSpan -> addStyle( // For <span style=color:blue> tag.
                    SpanStyle(color = Color.Blue),
                    start,
                    end
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

**3rd - Call `HtmlCompat.fromHtml()`**

As a last step before sending the `AnnotatedString` to the `Text()` composable we need to call the target `String` on `HtmlCompat.fromHtml()` method and also the new `toAnnotatedString()` extension function:

```
val textAsAnnotatedString = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
    stringResource(id = R.string.styled_text),
    HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT
).toAnnotatedString()
```

**4th - Show it on `Text()`**

And then just show it on your target `Text()` composable:

```
Text(text = textAsAnnotatedString)
```

**Note**: you can add lot's of *"style interpreter"* inside of `toAnnotatedString()`.

The down below print *(everything inside of the red rectangle)* is from a composable `SnackBar` on my Android project using the same above strategy.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for solution. @Thiengo Do you know how can I provide support for `<li>`, `<ol>`, `<ul>` in this compose TextView?

Answer (score -1):

Currently, you can use `AnnotatedString` class in order to show styled texts within a `Text` component. I will show you an example:

```
Text(
    text = buildAnnotatedString {
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Thin)) {
            append(stringResource(id = R.string.thin_string))
        }
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)) {
            append(stringResource(id = R.string.bold_string))
        }
    },
)
```

Depending on the style you assign, you will get a text with the style of the red highlight

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSMMB.png

For more info: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text?hl=nl#multiple-styles